# Transaction or variable declaration error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, transactions, syntax-error

I just started learning about transactions and stored procedures and I'm trying to get myself familiar with different ways of assigning values from result set to variables.

What could be causing the error on `DECLARE var_CurcId INT DEFAULT 0;`

Here's what I've done so far.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCurriculumWithSchoolYear`(IN p_subjectName varchar(50), IN p_yrLevel varchar(30), IN p_desc TEXT, IN p_creator varchar(20))
BEGIN

    DECLARE hasError BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET hasError = 1;

    DECLARE var_CurcId INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE var_syStart INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_syEnd INT DEFAULT 0;

        START TRANSACTION;

        -- 1 insert statement to curriculum table
            INSERT INTO curriculum(`name`,`yearLevel`,`description`,`creator`)
            VALUES(p_subjectName,p_yrLevel,p_desc,p_creator);
        -- 2 insert statement to schoolyearcurriculum table

            INSERT INTO schoolyearcurriculums(curriculumId,syStart,syEnd)
            VALUES(var_CurcId,var_syStart,var_syEnd);

        IF `hasError` THEN
            ROLLBACK; -- if error occurs to any of the insert, select statements above, undo it
        ELSE 
            COMMIT; -- if all insert, select statement is successful, execute.
            SELECT 'Successfully Inserted Information';
        END IF;
END;
```

The erorr on the declaration of `var_CurcId` variable is saying `Syntax error: unexpected 'var_CurcId' (identifier)`

I'm new to this so I hope you can help me. I'm still trying different ways such as using the `:=` operator and `select into` and `set`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  Just put all the declarations before the handler:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addCurriculumWithSchoolYear`(IN p_subjectName varchar(50), IN p_yrLevel varchar(30), IN p_desc TEXT, IN p_creator varchar(20))
BEGIN  
    DECLARE hasError BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_CurcId INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE var_syStart INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_syEnd INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET hasError = 1;

END
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c086f2) is a SQL Fiddle.

In a `BEGIN`/`END` block, all the `DECLARE`s must be the first statements.  Usually the handler is after the variable declarations; I didn't realize this was required, however, until testing it.

Comment: Thanks. You solved it! I didn't know that Handler has to go after variable declaration. I thought that all DECLARE statement can be put anywhere. I appreciate the help. Another learning added to my knowledge.